# Help me find a recap of an adventure where different party/same players, visit village

Tags: product-identification, story

A couple years back I found a text about a player recapping one of their most memorable pen&paper sessions. I found it in a forum thread where people shared some of their most memorable pen&paper experiences. 
I remember the overall story, but I desperately want to read this again and I was therefore hoping that one of you can link me to the source. Here is what I remember:

A group had to go to a village for some reason. They were given some sort of medicine or drug that helped them reach that place a bit more quickly.

When they arrived they found that the village was apparantly inhabited by bizarre creatures. They went on a killing spree and ended all of them.

A couple weeks later they continued their game but were using different characters. Those characters also made their way to the village. When they arrived they found everyone slaughtered. No creatures though, just normal human beings. 
They then somehow figured out that their other party was affected by that drug, which made them more or less crazy.

I remember that the recap was written extremely well. Does anyone know where I can find that by any chance?

Unfortunately I cannot also not remember which system this was in.

Comment: Was it an officially published product, or just a random guy blogging?

Comment: Also, do you have a best guess of what system it was? D&D? FATE? Something else?

Comment: I dont think it was a released adventure, but rather someone came up with it.
It was in a forum where people shared their favorite adventures. It was a rather huge thread iirc, therefore I thought maybe someone here stumbled across it as well. I know, pretty useless information. Dont even know which system it was. Feel free to close this question down if its terrible. Will have to level up my google skills.